# How to assert if a BitVecVal is contained in a set of BitVec in Z3Py?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am new to Z3Py and have the following problem:

I have a number of BitVecVals `myset = [BitVecVal(13,11), BitVecVal(23,11),..., BitVecVal(42,11)]` and a variable `x = BitVec('x',11)`. Is there any way to formulate the constraint that `x` must be contained in `myset` without hard-coding it (since I have different test-cases for `myset`)?

Comment: There are other ways (e.g. enumeration types, see https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide), but the most efficient way is probably to just create a big OR assertion of (= x val) expressions. In Python that's easily constructed by running over your array of values as it doesn't have a huge number of entries.